# Single SQL Query to Delete records in two tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net

These are my tables:

```
tbl_student (studID,Firstname)
```

My studid is **priid**

```
finger_template(Detail_ID,FingerprintMask)
```

I want to delete the record in `tbl_student` and `finger_template`. Here's my Query:

> `command = New MySqlCommand("DELETE from tbl_student where studid='" & priid & "'", connection, transaction)`

Hope someone will help

Comment: How are these 2 tables connected? Because if they are not connected, then you cannot delete from both of them using a single delete command, you need 2. Although, you can issue both delete commands in a single call.

Comment: Yes it is connected by studID sir.

Comment: If the tables has link together this is quite easy, are they connected to each other (tables)? -- By [MattMagallo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4061583/matt-magallo)

Comment: Yes sir .Im sorry im newbie :(

Comment: @MykeeBrylleSepulveda if they are connected in mysql(innoDB) you could just remove the PrimaryKey and all the ForeignKey will be removed -- By [MattMagallo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4061583/matt-magallo)

Comment: @MattMagallo how about my priid sir ??

Comment: My recommendation is the innodb engine and cascading deletes for those  with concern over data and referential integrity

Answer (score 1):

Table: tbl_student

```
+-------------+-----------+
| studID (PK) | Firstname |
+-------------+-----------+
| **000001**  | John      |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Table: finger_template

```
+----------------+-----------------+-------------+
| Detail_ID (PK) | FingerprintMask | studID (FK) |
+----------------+-----------------+-------------+
| 000001         | SampleMask      | **000001**  |
+----------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

If the tbl_student `studID` PK is link to finger_template `stuID` FK
you could just simply remove the `studID` PK and the FK will be remove as well `DELETE FROM tbl_student WHERE studID=000001`

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: sorry @BhargavRao i can't comment yet because my rep is still not enough..:(

Comment: I have added it as a comment, you can delete your ans if you feel like. Regards

Comment: @MattMagallo Then don't answer a comment! `:)`

Comment: One last comment sir @BhargavRao,
To: @mykee
if they are connected in mysql(innoDB) you could just remove the `PrimaryKey` and all the `ForeignKey` will be removed

Comment: done, (Hope it is the last :P )

Comment: @PraveenKumar, sorry i ddnt mean to my rep is still not enough so im force to do so, my appologies guys

Comment: @MattMagallo No worries. I guess it is better to delete this answer at this point, and if you get the answer, edit it and then undelete it.